# Пропали метки из профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, метки

У [моего профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/athari) отсутствует статистика по меткам, хотя ответы, репутация и прочее на месте. У [профиля на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/athari) все метки есть. Возможно, это последствие слияния аккаунтов.

Плюс надпись "This user has not *participated* in any tags" неверно переведена как "Вы не *назначали* каких-либо меток".

Comment: все еще актуально? Вроде вижу статистику.